# iPhone 5 broken glass replacement

Tags: iphone

My friend recently broke his iPhone 5. He has broken just the front glass. Everything works very fine: LCD, touch screen, etc…

Is there any possibility to change only the front glass that costs, on eBay, [9.99$](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Replacement-Black-Front-Screen-Cover-Glass-Lens-Tools-for-iPhone-5-5G-VJGS116-/290867959411?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item43b914d673)? Not whole digitizer with LCD? I've not found any video with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPhone 5's front glass is part of the LCD screen, not as in the iPhone 4 where you could only change the back glass (I am almost sure that the front glass in iPhone 4/4S was also separate from the screen).

Therefore, must change the whole screen.

Comment: The front glass on the 4/4S was separate from the screen, so you could change that as well.

Comment: Thx, that's all I want to know.